# Runtime error in Opencv text module sample code "webcam_demo"

Tags: opencv, text-recognition

When I run other samples code of module text , everything is well. But when I tried to run webcam_demo program I got this error:

```
Error: Illegal min or max specification!
"Fatal error encountered!" == NULL:Error:Assert failed:in file globaloc.cpp, line 75
```

The debugger breaks execution right before this line:

```
ocrs.push_back(OCRTesseract::create());
```

[webcam_demo.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/webcam_demo.cpp)

Thank you for helping out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem, when using tesseract with OpenCV.
When I moved initialization before anything else, it started to work.

Comment: what do you mean with "initialization before anything?"

Comment: I moved tesseract initialization to first line of main function. I am not sure why that worked.